# SAP Gateway - Unexpected text for XML-ABAP transformation

Tags: abap, sap-gateway

URL Call from Gateway: `/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMU_SHOP_MENU_SRV/ShopMenuSet?$expand=Menu/Menu_Section/Menu_Content/Menu_Item_Deal/Deal_Articles/Article_Modifier/Modifier_Class/Modifier_Group/Modifier_Options,Menu/Menu_Section/Menu_Content/Menu_Item_Deal/Prices,Menu/Menu_Section/Menu_Content/Article_Modifier/Modifier_Class/Modifier_Group/Modifier_Options.`

DDIC Structures for the above were imported individually in SAP Gateway Service Builder (`SEGW`) and linked via associations.

This calls the `/IWBEP/IF_MGW_APPL_SRV_RUNTIME~GET_EXPANDED_ENTITYSET` method in SAP.

```
DATA: ls_shop_menu   TYPE zmu_s_shop_menu.
    
APPEND 'MENU/MENU_SECTION/MENU_CONTENT/MENU_ITEM_DEAL/DEAL_ARTICLES/ARTICLE_MODIFIER/MODIFIER_CLASS/MODIFIER_GROUP/MODIFIER_OPTIONS' TO et_expanded_tech_clauses.
APPEND 'MENU/MENU_SECTION/MENU_CONTENT/MENU_ITEM_DEAL/PRICES' TO et_expanded_tech_clauses.
APPEND 'MENU/MENU_SECTION/MENU_CONTENT/ARTICLE_MODIFIER/MODIFIER_CLASS/MODIFIER_GROUP/MODIFIER_OPTIONS' TO et_expanded_tech_clauses.
CALL METHOD zmu_menu_ctrl=>get_menu_for_shop
          EXPORTING
            iv_shop            = '0005'
            iv_date            = sy-datum
            iv_price_condition = ''
            iv_price_list_type = ''
          IMPORTING
            rs_shop            = ls_shop_menu.
    
copy_data_to_ref(
             EXPORTING
             is_data = ls_shop_menu
             CHANGING
             cr_data = er_entityset
             ).
```

ER_ENTITYSET is populated fine.

This 500 error:

> Unexpected text for XML-ABAP transformation

occurs in the method `MOVE_CORRESPONDING` in class `/IWBEP/CL_MGW_DATA_HELPER`:

```
    lo_xml_reader = cl_sxml_string_reader=>create( lv_xdoc ).
        lo_xml_reader->next_node( ).
        CALL TRANSFORMATION /iwbep/st_any_data
          SOURCE XML lo_xml_reader
          RESULT data = <ls_target_data>.
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to correctly set up a nested structure on `SEGW` side which can handle the structure passed back?

I've no idea where I'm going wrong.

Comment: give the dump from ST22, it seems that some of your structures are broken

Answer (score 0):

since you are in an entityset method, you must pass a table type to copy_data_to_ref. Instead of ls_shop_menu, pass lt_shop_menu, with lt_shop_menu being a table type of ls_shop_menu. i.e.

append ls_shop_menu to lt_shop_menu.

copy_data_to_ref(
EXPORTING
is_data = lt_shop_menu
CHANGING
cr_data = er_entityset
).